# How to limit maximum number of characters that can be typed into input field? maxlength attribute not working

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning-aura-components, jquery, aura-attribute

I'm using the UIInputField.

I want to limit the numbers of characters that can be typed into input field, however, there is an issue. I tried using the "**maxlength**" attribute, but it doesn't effect the code at all when it should. The "maxlength" only works for **ui:inputText** but not for **ui:inputNumber**. Obviously the lightning developer guide is wrong, because maxlength attribute doesn't have any effect for inputNumber, though it is recognized as a valid attribute.

If someone can please show me how to set the maxlength for this field that would be great. I believe we need to create a javascript function, but I don't know how since I'm not familiar with the syntax of it at all. If someone can walk me through this step by step and show me the code, that would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I am not allowed to code this in my VFP. I can only do this in my JS controller and lightning component.

Comment: If the documentation says it should work, you should be speaking to @metadaddy or someone that can actually speak with the internal team to see why it is *not* working as documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
({
    limitCharacterTo : function(element, charLimit, evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        if(element.value.length >= charLimit && charCode != 8) {
           return false;
        }
    }
})
```

I haven't tried this in lightning, but if you can bind this to the aura:id field, you can call this function on keypress and pass in the desired parameters.

Comment: I copied and pasted your JS and added the following code to the inputNumber field code that I have above: "keypress = {"!limitCharacterTo};", and it still doesn't work. Am I binding this to the field wrong? What can possibly be the issue?

Comment: It should be keypress = "{!c.limitCharacterTo};"

Comment: Tried adding another parameter"component"?

Comment: What parameters are you passing ?cuz it looks like its not getting that element correctly.

Comment: I got this to work employing my own method. The problem is that Lightning isn't fully developed, and has holes in its functionalities. I did some work-arounds to get this method to work by using arrays and setting attributes to those arrays.